# How to set class name of <li> and <a> inside the nav menu in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How can I make a nav menu like

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav_menu">
        <li class="nav_menu_li"><a href="" class="link"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I add class name of `<li>` and `<a>` as I like most by using

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main_menu' ) ); ?>
```

This wordpress function. How can I set dynamic menu in wp with my own class name inside `<li>` and `<a>`?

Comment: I'm a new user in stack overflow. so i am not fluent here. would you please clear it again?

Comment: Your original post used markup that made your question hard to read. I've removed that markup. Please format your future questions using simple text, as I've done above.